# how to click two identical attributes with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, button, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In ***firepath*** I saw two identical attributes, firepath has two results.

Here is the  highlighted HTML code below in firebug:

```
<button class="list_header_search_toggle icon-search btn btn-icon table-btn-lg" style="margin-left:0px">
```

And below is the whole code:

```
<button class="list_header_search_toggle icon-search btn btn-icon table-btn-lg" style="margin-left:0px">
<span class="sr-only">Search</span>
</button>
```

NOTE: There is only 1 search button, I search it every where and there is only 1 but it shows two??

***How to code this in selenium web driver?***

The snippet from firepath:

[image]

**Update:**

Html code image, from firepath:

[image]

Comment: Can you share `site` Url or `Html`?

Comment: Try:`.//button[@id='hdr_problem_task']/th[2]/button[0]`
`.//button[@id='hdr_problem_task']/th[2]/button[1]`
`.//button[@id='hdr_problem_task']/th[2]/button[2]`

Comment: Use `indexing` after completion of your xpath.

Comment: you can use an other selector LinkText for example !!

Comment: @RichardMadsi have a look [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Nazar, sure I will add the html for this. =)

Comment: @nazar_art  `<button class="list_header_search_toggle icon-search btn btn-icon table-btn-lg" style="margin-left:0px">`

Comment: @nazar_art that is the highlights in firebug

Comment: @nazar_art `<button class="list_header_search_toggle icon-search btn btn-icon table-btn-lg" style="margin-left:0px">
<span class="sr-only">Search</span>
</button>` but this the whole code I beleive

Comment: @RichardMadsi If you want to add an image to post just press `Ctrl` + `G` => select image. Make link for image is not the best idea, to my mind.

Comment: Thanks for the Info!

Answer (score 2):

You can use **XPath functions**, for example:

- `position()` returns the position of element at DOM

> //button[@id='hdr_problem_task']/th[2]/button[position()=1]

- `last()`

> //button[@id='hdr_problem_task']/th[2]/button[last()]

- something like ***first()*** doesn't exist, instead of this you can use index:

> //button[@id='hdr_problem_task']/th[2]/button[1]

Also if `button` has some text you can use it as well:

> //button[@id='hdr_problem_task']/th[2]/button[text()='button name']

or with `contains()`

> //button[@id='hdr_problem_task']/th[2]/button[contains(text(), 'button name')]

**UPDATE:**

The button has name `Search` you can use XPath with - `contains()`.

One more small suggestion, don't forget about future support. And instead of the following locator:

> //*[@id='hdr_problem_task']/th[2]/button

Much better will be:

> //button[@id='hdr_problem_task']/th[2]/button

Answer (score 0):

You can use **th** tag's **name** attribute value in order to recognize the correct **Search** button, as shown below:

```
//th[@name='search'][1]/button/span[text()='Search']
```

Let me know, whether it works for you.

Comment: the code  is visible in firepath and it has two the same results:                    1rst Results: `<span class="sr-only">Search</span>`
2nd Results:  `<span class="sr-only">Search</span>`

Comment: but it is not visible in Eclipse when I ran it

Comment: What exception/error do you see when you run code using above xpath?